# How to change entry on Xamarin for android?

Tags: android, xamarin

My problem is on Android, my `Entry` is to small so I need to change the `Entry` on android only.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: entry  == edittext(PlainText) control or what?

Comment: Are you using Xamarin.Forms? If so you can use custom renderers. Custom renderers are used to custumize views for each platform.

Answer (score 1):

In Xamarin.Forms you can use the following in XAML. Same thing can easily be achieved in code-behind.

```
                <Entry Text="My special label">
                  <Entry.WidthRequest>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Double"
                                iOS="20"
                                WinPhone="20"
                                Android="40" />  
                  </Entry.WidthRequest>
                </Entry>
```

Take a look at Xamarin guide for [platform specific tweeks](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/platform-specifics/).